# Sampling a 1D texture based on values from a 2D texture

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am filling a 2D texture with GLubyte from floating point values of R (real numbers) mapped to (0,1) and multiplied by 255 giving values (0, 255). Saving is as GL_R8 as I only need 1 value from the texture. This can for example represent a mathematical function.

I also upload a 1d texture to work as a colormap/colorbar. I then sample from the 1D texture based on the values from my 2D texture.

This is how my fragment shaders works:

```
#version 400
in vec2 f_textureCoord;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D textureData;
uniform sampler1D colorBar;


void main() {
    /* Values in the sampler are on (0, 1) * 255 => (0, 255) */
    vec3 texColor = texture2D(textureData, f_textureCoord).rgb;
    float s = texColor.r;

    /* Use the texture value as a coordinate in the 1D colorbar texture */
    vec3 color = texture1D(colorBar, s).rgb;

    float val = color.r;
    FragColor = vec4(val, val, val, 1);
}
```

Using this I get the following error:

> glValidateProgram: Validation Error: Samplers of different types point
>   to the same texture unit

However, my code works as expected, at least the rendering result!

My questions are:

1) Why do I get this error/warning? --- *Answered in comments...*

2) Is this the correct approach to what I am trying to do? Should I use another form of buffer instead of saving my function values in a 2D texture?

3) I assume that I will run into problems when my math function (filling the 2D texture) exceeds some texture size limit. Any recommendations on how I should proceed to work around this?

Comment: I suspect you're binding the same texture unit to both samplers. Though why it would work is beyond me.

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: @genpfault: I use #version 400, it is at compile time..

Comment: @thomas: but glValidateProgram() is called at the shader compilation stage. This is before I even upload or render any texture buffer.. So it only relates to the GLSL code?

Comment: Ah, but `glValidateProgram()` also validates the state. Right after compilation, both samplers point at texture unit 0. In fact this very error (in other wording) is mentioned in the manpage: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glValidateProgram.xml So you'd typically want to call this function right before you start rendering, no sooner.

Comment: @thomas: thanks, that makes sense. As I understand now, I need to have my texture binding in place before calling the validate function...

Comment: @Thomas: How about you make this an answer, so that toeplitz can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Call glValidateProgram before your glDraw* command to check if you set up uniform and attribute locations correctly. So the wrong warning is issued because both sampler texture units are still zero after program linking.

2.) If this is about displaying the results of you function using a color index, it's ok.
If I understand it right textureData contains only grey values. If you need only one color component from the texture, you should write

```
float s = texture2D(textureData, f_textureCoord).r;
```

3.) If you need to display more data than you can put into a single texture, you will have to use tiling (i.e split the data in several textures and do several draws).

Comment: is it possible to avoid seams using tiling technique?

Comment: @toeplitz: depending on the interpolation used, you will need to have small overlapping regions to avoid seams

Answer (score 0):

`glValidateProgram` is for detecting if the program can be used to render with the *current OpenGL state*. This includes things like the current bindings for textures, uniform buffers, and any other things that textures directly access (draw buffers and vertex attributes are not part of this list).